# Interpretation of log transformed negatively skewed dependent variable

Tags: multiple-regression, data-transformation

I am running multiple regression analysis and my dependent variable is not normally distributed (skewness=-1.794 and kurtosis: 4.643). In order to correct this, I applied log transformation but because it is negatively skewed I used this formula: $log(1+max value of DV - DV)$. The inversely and log transformed DV was closer to normally distributed (though inverse transformation was much closer, I still chose log transformation as there is literature on how to interpret log transformation, while none on how to interpret inverse transformation is available to me).

When I run the regression on the transformed DV, I got negative values for unstandardised b which implies that increase in one unit of the predictor would lead to beta*100% decrease in DV. But it is very well known in literature that the increase of that independent variable cannot cause decrease in the dependent variable. I also see reversal of the signs of beta coefficients for some of the other independent variables (as I would expect also to see the increase in both dependent and indepenent variables, not one increase and other decrease).

Does anyone know whether this formula applied to the negatively skewed variable can actually produce such a result (reversal of signs), or something else is wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: A couple points: 1) OLS regression does NOT require that the DV be normally distributed, it requires that the error, as estimated by the residuals, be normally distributed. 2) Look into Box-Cox transformations (lots of info on the web).

Comment: @PeterFlom Thanks, Peter, for your reply. It is written in literature that there are 2 strategies for checking conformity to assumptions: pre analysis (checking variables prior to running regression); and post analysis (looking at the pattern of residuals for assumptions evaluation). I think the argument is that if there is no normality, it would be detectable in both pre and post analysis. I followed the first one.

Comment: Hi @Beka I don't know where you read that. It is not true. The assumptions of OLS regression are not about the DV, and you *can* have a non-normal DV with normal residuals (usually you don't, but it is possible).

Comment: @PeterFlom Thank you, again. I have read it the lecture notes for the data analysis course given at one university.

Comment: Hi @Beka, your comment **"if there is no normality, it would be detectable in both pre and post analysis"** is a common belief but it is not true in general (+1, Peter). It's not difficult to give an example where the errors are normal but the outcome variable itself is not - just make your predictor(s) highly skewed! For an `R` example, take `x <- rexp(200); y <- 1 + 2*x + rnorm(200)` - the errors are normal but `y` is not. _Note:_ non-normal predictors are **not** a violation of the model assumptions.

Comment: @PeterFlom Why would you say you usually don't? Due to the influence of the predictors I would say that it is almost the standard case.

Comment: @Erik In my experience, if the DV is very non-normal, the residuals usually are. Does your experience differ?

Comment: @macro +1 nice easy example.

Comment: @Beka I'm guessing those notes were from a course given by a non-statistician.

Comment: It does depend on the type of non-normality. If you have a very important binary predictor I would expect bimodality in the dependant. Easiest example is height with gender as the predictor. I work with treatments and powerful gender effects a lot, so this is perhaps why I see that so often. It's also usual for skewness in an important continous predictor to transfer to the dependant. In this case I also often have normal residuals. Perhaps you are used to the case that your predictors are roughly normally distributed? Of course, it also depends on what you define as "very non-normal" :)

Comment: @Erik, **"Perhaps you are used to the case that your predictors are roughly normally distributed? In this case I would expect that you are right."** - good point. If all of the predictors are normally distributed then checking the errors for normality by looking at the dependent variable is a reasonable thing to do, since the sum of normally distributed variables is normal.

Comment: @Beka Contrary to what Peter and Macro are saying I believe in linear regression the assumption is that the x variables IVs are fixed and known while the DV is therefore normally distributed conditional on thevalues for the DVs.  I don't understand why they keep insisting that the DV need not be normal.  Assuming the error term is normal that can only happen if you assume the xs are selected from a probability distribution.

Comment: @Michael: First, when the OP was talking about checking for normality pre-analysis this seemed to pretty clearly suggest checking the _marginal distribution_ of the outcome for normality, which is clearly not what you want to do (we can agree on that, right? If not, see my example). Second, the conditional distribution of the outcome given the predictors will only be normal (I assume this is the conditional distribution you were referring to, although the typos make it unclear - it looks like you said DV when you meant IV at least once) if the errors are normal. What is the controversy here??

Comment: @Macro Peter contually says that the assumption in OLS is only that the residuals be normally distributed and the DV need not be normally distributed. MY point (which may only be a disagreement with him, not sure) is that the Xs or IVs are fixed and known and not random.  The sum of squares is only minimized in the direction of y (the DV) because of this assumption.  Hence the conditional distribution of y given the values for the xs is normal because the error term is assumed to have a normal distribution.

Comment: It doesn't make sense in this context to talk about the unconditional distribution of y being non-normal. But this seems to be an assertion that Peter Flom makes repeatedly on this site (i.e. that y can have a non-normal unconditional distribution).

Comment: @Michael, OK. All I'm saying (and I think Peter, as well) is that the distribution of $Y|X$ can be normal while the marginal distribution of $Y$ is not. Therefore, checking the response variable, $Y$, for normality, **alone**, doesn't check the "normality" assumption of the model - it actually tests a much stronger assumption (i.e. that the errors **and** all of the predictors are normal). Many novices misinterpret what they learn in stat classes and do exactly that. This misunderstanding comes up on this site (and in teaching undergrads) frequently so I think Peter's comment is valuable.

Comment: @Michael I think I see what you mean. Since the x do not come from a probability distribution but are fixed it makes no sense look at the unconditional distribution of y, because that depends on the fixed x. Is that correct? However, I think it is more proper to regard some x's as also being random. In practice they are often a random sample of some larger population after all. The assumption of the mathematics behind linear regression is not that the x do not come from some random population but just that they are measured without error.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Thank you a lot, Michael. I have noticed that there are a lot of contradictory opinions in statistics, and  it makes me more confused when I have to decide which path to follow. Still I do not know if it is possible that by only wrongly (?) choosing log transformation I get the opposite sign of relationship (opposite than expected), or it is just indication that something else is wrong.

Comment: Beka, @Peter has given you a good answer to that already: your particular transformation is an *order-reversing* one. As far as contradictory opinions go, I urge you to investigate the bases for those opinions: those that are bare assertions or appeals to authority ("so-and-so says..." or "I believe...") can be ignored, while those that provide references can be checked, but best of all are those that are accompanied by careful, clear reasons and do not shy away from mathematics where that can help: you can check those yourself and decide whether they apply in your case.

Comment: Again, thanks everyone for comments, suggestions, corrections, opinions. Assuming that I would need to transform my variables after inspection of residuals, will the formula applied for negative skewness (1+max value of DV-DV) produce the inverse relation between DV and IVs?

Comment: @Macro One final remark on this point.  I understand that it is not appropriate to look at the distribution of the ys overall to test for normality.  Of course the way the xs distribute will affect how the ys look.  I would just say that it is the same to look at the ys conditioned on the x values to cehck normality as it is to look at the residuals.  The only difference being that it may not be possible to do this for each set of ys given the xs as the xs may not be repeated. Basically we are all in agreement and the difference is terminology.

Comment: I do not like talking about the unconditional distribution of the ys.  It implies that the xs are somehow random.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I am not sure if we even disagree. The OP *was* talking about the unconditional distribution of Y (whether you like to talk about it or not). I agree that it is Y|X that has to be normal; but the assumptions for the linear model are given about the residuals. I've seen them stated thus in many books on regression; unfortunately my books are at my office and I am home.

Comment: Beka First of all, I don't think that what looks like a disagreement between @Michael and me really is one - at least, not as it concerns your post. Second, there is no hint of disagreement about what your transformation does - that is, it inverts the variable - I showed this in my code, it also follows from the transformation itself.

Comment: @PeterFlom  Given the comments of Macro I agree that we all agree about the assumptions of the linear model using OLS.  I am just being a little picky about even mentioning an unconditional distribution for y.  But I understand the point you are trying to get across to the OPs.

Comment: @MichaelChernick  Cool. A lot of our seeming disagreements seem to wind up being about terminology.

Comment: @PeterFlom Thanks Peter. I did not refer to this particular disagreement about my analysis, but in general, by reading different papers and books in statistics I can see that statisticians disagree a lot. That was my comment about. Thanks for the code as well but it was not clear to me what it was supposed to show me as I am not used to using and applying codes for statistical analysis but rather using already available functions in the software. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Beka Statisticians tend to be mathematical and think about things very precisely.  I think that is why you will see us getting into a lot of disputes and debates.  But that is healthy.  To really see harsh debate among statisticians you should go back in history to Fisher vs Neyman and Fisher vs Karl Pearson.  We also have foundational issues Bayesian vs frequentist that may not be commonly found in other fields.  But I think you will find that statistics is based on mathematics and theory dervied using mathematics and that on most technical points we will agree.

Answer (score 2):

Your original x and your transformed x are inversely related, so, naturally, any relationship that is positive on one will be negative on the other. One way to see this inverse relationship is

```
x <- rnorm(100)
x2 <- log(1 + max(x) - x)
plot(x, x2)
```

(I used a normally distributed X here, but it does not matter for these purposes; you could substitute your variable and its transformation).

Further explanation after reading one of @Beka 's comments above.

x2 is a transformed version of x, using the transformation you used. Then I plotted x vs. x2. When x goes up, x2 goes down. So, any relationship between x and some other variable will be reversed between x2 and that variable.

In other words, your findings do not contradict earlier work.